# Entity Framework - CodeFirst, no database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have been playing around with EF6 CodeFirst and Migrations. So far all good. But there is one thing I don't understand (conceptually):

In my specific case I am determining the database to connect to at runtime (via some external config XML / JSON or similar). So during development I am a) not certain what database it is I am working with and b) do not necessarily have one available. But EF still requires one, because otherwise I cannot use Update-Database. And if I cannot use Update-Database, I cannot scaffold further migrations.

Is there something I am missing or do I necessarily need a dev-database to develop something using EF6?

The real problem I face is that Update-Database fails with an error telling me that connecting to a DB failed.

Comment: Don't you want to do integration testing? Just install SQL Express on your development machine.

Comment: Why donb't you use a local DB while in Debug mode and switch to your config connection string when switching to Release?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You can target different machines/databases by changing the connection string. Creating a database is a job for the DBA because bad/default configurations that are good for development are awful for production (eg putting the database and log file in C:). Moreover, different products have completely different database settings. An ORM like EF can neither know all of them nor decide by itself what to use. Migrations is about creating/updating a schema, not creating the entire database from scratch.

Comment: Testing is also done using a special configuration that points to MS SQL Server.
Using LocalDB would be ok for me, but for some reason I can't get it to work. I first wanted to check if I *really* need one before looking into that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Sure, you're talking about runtime. I am talking about design-time. I do not create databases. I attach to existing ones. And update it's schema.

Comment: Then what do you men "do not necessarily have one available"?

Comment: I am on my development PC that does not have any databases installed. I want to scaffold some simple migrations. Next time I use my project on a DB the migration should be applied.